# Webflux: Assembly vs Execution of then()

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactor

I'm trying to understand the difference b/w flatmap vs then. I see then() gets executed at assembly time. Below are the test and output. Thoughts?

```
@Test
public void test() {
    final Mono<String> test = Mono.just(3)
            .flatMap(i -> integer(i))
            .flatMap(s -> hello())
            .then(f());

    test.log().subscribe(str -> System.out.println(str));
}

private Mono<String> f() {
    System.out.println("Returning f");
    return Mono.just("f");
}

private Mono<String> hello () {
    System.out.println("Returning hello");
    return Mono.just("Hello");
}

private Mono<Integer> integer(Integer i) {
    if (i == 3) {
        System.out.println("Returning 3");
        return Mono.just(3);
    }
    System.out.println("Throwing exception");
    return Mono.error(new Exception(""));
}
```

Output

```
11:13:57.456 [main] DEBUG reactor.util.Loggers$LoggerFactory - Using Slf4j logging framework
Returning f
11:13:57.474 [main] INFO reactor.Mono.IgnoreThen.1 - | onSubscribe([Fuseable] MonoIgnoreThen.ThenIgnoreMain)
11:13:57.477 [main] INFO reactor.Mono.IgnoreThen.1 - | request(unbounded)
Returning 3
Returning hello
11:13:57.570 [main] INFO reactor.Mono.IgnoreThen.1 - | onNext(f)
f
11:13:57.571 [main] INFO reactor.Mono.IgnoreThen.1 - | onComplete()
```

My question is why does `Returning f` in function f() get printed during at assembly time?

Comment: You are running the function directly in `then`, it isn't deferred with a lambda like the other methods. As such it runs as soon as the initial mono is assembled. This is a more a java question than reactor.

Comment: Thanks. But `then` is supposed to wait for the `flatmap` to complete right?

Comment: It does, the Mono inside only emits data after the previous Mono/Flux has completed. The function itself runs immediately though. Try for example changing the method body for `f()` to `return Mono.just("f").doOnNext(s -> System.out.println("Returning f"));`

Comment: Ahh got it. On the same lines why in hello() `System.out.println("Returning hello");` is not executed during assembly time?

Comment: The lambda is a function, the method it refers to is called later. As I said in the first comment, that's more of basics of java question though, so you will likely find tons of resources that explain it in better detail than I can in comments.